# How can a car travelling at a higher speed may cause it to lift off from the ground?

Tags: aerodynamics, car

Many Sports cars and other high speed and performance ground vehicles have a rear wing attached to its rear, and a splitter attached to its front. From what I understand, the rear wing (which takes the shape of an airfoil) will cause negative lift, hence pressing the rear tires while the splitters attached at the front of the car will make more air pass from the top of the vehicle while less air passes from the bottom of it, and therefore this also generates a negative lift and thus the front tires also gets pressed against the ground. If only any one of them is tacked to the car, then a net moment might be created (negative lift coming from anyone of these and a positive lift coming from the car itself) and the car might spin/turn about its center of gravity in the air.

All of this is done because at high speeds, the car itself generates lift. I couldn't understand that how can a car actually generate lift at all? I mean if I was a car designer, I wouldn't shape the car in such a way that the aerodynamics can actually make it to lift off from the ground. Some say that you cannot control it, and it is bound to happen at high speeds because the effect of lift becomes more prominent at high speeds. Well, for a lift to originate, there must be high pressure at the bottom of the car and low pressure on the top. The amount of air passing from the top of the car appears to be more than the air passing from the bottom. And since more air passing means higher pressure should be there, so I couldn't comprehend that still how can a car generate lift? Because literally the air has such a small room to pass from the bottom (and hence generate high pressure there) relative to it passing from the top of the car.

Comment: Do some research - there have been cases where racing cars "took flight" with serious / fatal results. Also check out the term "Ground effect" also check out aircraft.

Comment: "*The amount of air passing from the top of the car appears to be more than the air passing from the bottom. And since more air passing means higher pressure should be there*" Last time I checked, air is compressible and you can't just look at empty volumes and compare their size to guess pressure.

Comment: @DKNguyen, so what you mean is that its not because more air is actually passing from the bottom of the car and less air on the top, its because of the less space (volume) that the air beneath the car has which generates higher pressure at bottom of the car, while a lot more space (volume) on the top hence a lesser pressure there [Boyle's Law]. But this guy here says what I have exactly written in my post: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AXjiThF1LXU&ab_channel=DonutMedia

Comment: I'm saying that you can't just say less space = less air = less pressure. Overly simplistic. The air is not in a closed container. Don't use dumbed down Youtube videos as your only source on complicated topics. Case in point: That Youtube video talks about the equal transit time theory which is demonstrably *wrong* and widespread. Symmetrical and flat wings can produce lift, and airplanes produce more lift close to the ground via ground effect.

Comment: @DKNguyen, we both agree the more amount of air molecules lying in a same volume, the greater the pressure. Now, for a car to generate lift, it must have higher pressure at bottom. First possibility is more air passes from the bottom (so higher air molecules and higher pressure), second possibility is same (or even lesser) amount of air passes from the bottom than at the top, but since the volume is smaller in the bottom of the car (because of small distance to the road), hence higher pressure. Which one is true?

Comment: If you have got any other possibilities, you may let me know. I could have also given the concept of equal transient time for this as a third possibility, but you have already written how that is proven to be wrong, so I won't name it.

Comment: I would think that in large part it is simply due to the fact that the nose of the car can only rotate away from the road and that rotation is unstable because it further increases the AOA which is unstable because it is rotating around the rear wheels further increasing AOA. Any pertubation in airflow, road or vibration that causes the nose to lift just a bit in the presence of sufficiently strong airflow keeps it moving in that direction.  You see the same thing with a flat cardboard box laying on the ground in wind.

Comment: The tail lifting is the other way to rotate, but that is stable, just like how elevators are stable while canards are not.

Comment: @DKNguyen, But what would cause the nose to lift UP A BIT? You are actually saying that if we somehow just get a certain (even tiny small) angle of attack on the car then the car will lift up. I agree. Yes, the aerodynamics of the car then can be thought of similar to that of an airfoil and its front will then lift off. Please watch drag racing videos where the car lifts off on the road solely due to high speed, since there is no rotation by steering and no bumps/vibration on the road at all.

Comment: @RameezUlHaq Anything could cause the nose to lift up a bit. That's what I'm saying. Could be the be a bump, hole, turbulence, anything. I ask you to think more critically. You don't seriously think the ground is perfectly smooth do you? There's also things like uneven deformation between front and rear.

Comment: @DKNguyen, I just don't agree that there is a need for the car to lift up a bit, to generate an angle of attack and then it will generate lift. I think if the car will even lift up the slightest, then it should be because of the lift, and lift only. Nothing else. Otherwise, that becomes conditional. If I have a disturbed airflow, if I have a bump or a vibration, then and only then the car will lift off from the ground, otherwise no. Again, watch the drag racing where the cars lift off without any apparent airflow pertubation, bumps or vibrations.

Comment: @RameezUlHaq You say conditional but the world is a noisy place. There are always disturbances. There are real world machines (electronic circuits, for example) that would not work in an ideal world because there is no noise or disturbances to initialize them. You talk as if you sitting behind a monitor displaying what a camera is recording at a distance lets you see everything going on in a race car up close. And that's all I have to say on the matter if that's what you continue to insist.

Comment: @DKNguyen, I have been to drag racing and I have observed it very closely. The tracks are built very carefully by keeping in mind that even if the smallest of bumps are allowed on these tracks, then it would loose the actual meaning and charm of drag racing. No rotation of the nose of car is allowed or aimed at. The cars begin the run when they feel there are no expected disturbances in airflow (although it can't be completely eliminated). The reason why I am emphasizing on Drag racing is because I believe lift off happens solely due to speed and acceleration, and nothing else.

Answer (score 1):

In a car or racecar, the lift is created because of the overall shape of the car, very roughly half a teardrop.

The flow of air bends around the body of a car, similar to how it bends around an airfoil, generating lift.

In racecars, they try to control the lift by as you mention by adding wings and splitters.

But if the car hits a bump or turns a tight turn it can become a projectile at fast speed, and it experiences changes in the angle of attack of those ailerons and they can become positive lift wings.

Many times in fast speed jerks the car or any projectile will pitch and rotate up to assume the best lift configuration just to offer the least drag.

Answer (score 0):

(**Work in progress** ... I can't finish this right now but most of the idea is here . I'll get back in a couple of hours).

The function of the splitter is very important in the scenario that is considered in this question.

As you mentioned most high speed cars have a splitter that redirects more air to pass from the top. Additionally, splitter has a small ground clearance. The small ground clearance mean reduced cross-section and forces the air to move faster underneath the car. The higher speed of air is equivalent to less static pressure. From the top side of the car the available cross-section is not bounded (unless you move in a tunnel). Basically the area that the air is affected can go with increasing speed (from the bottom side there is a hard limit).

Most commercial cars do not have a splitter mainly because, there needs to be  enough ground clearance for the car to be able to move in most roads without bumping into obstacles. Therefore at higher speed roughly the same proportion of air gets moved underneath the car but now it needs to move faster  (thus reducing more the pressure), while the top side is less affected. This creates a pressure difference which increases for higher speeds.

[image]

**Figure: splitter source [formula 1 dictionary](http://www.formula1-dictionary.net/splitter.html)**

The [Coanda effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coand%C4%83_effect) plays an important role here (hopefully, I'll continue later).

Comment: Weren't most splitters designed to make sure of cooling airflow for the brakes?

Comment: Imagine a car with no splitters, rear wing or spoilers whatsoever. Now, still the car can create a positive lift which may lift off the car from the ground. How does this happen? When car is not already designed like an airfoil of aircraft's wing (which is intentionally designed to result in a positive lift). The reason that I found while I researched about this is that more air can pass from the bottom of the car while less on the top, hence more air pressure on the bottom while less on top (similar to an aircraft's wing). But how? When there is such a small room for air to pass from bottom.

Comment: As the pavement surface is not built mirror perfect, the tyre will bounce off the pavement, especially driving at a very high speed that has a considerable amount of thrust. The lift is the combined effects of angled thrust + dynamic of wind. Also, think about hydroplaning.

Comment: If you are a motorcycle rider, you may have experienced that it's very easy to lift the front wheel from stationary - start the engine, put clutch into low gear, then simultaneously turn the fuel throttle to the maximum and release the brake, the bike will take off like airplane with very little help from your arms and body to turn the direction of the thrust.

Comment: @rameezulhaq Apologies but I still haven't found time to prepare some graphs that will make easier explaining. And the alternative (is large text explanations) is equally difficult right now.

Comment: @NMech, it is okay. You may comment here or edit your answer with additional details whenever you feel free.

Comment: Some road cars use the lift produced by the body to reduce load on tyres and save fuel.